# $x_{\alpha+1} = 2 (g(x_\alpha)) $ prove orbit reaches $2^p$

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, periodic-functions

I will make this simple, but hopefully it wont be too vague.

Let $x,n,q\in\mathbb{N}$.

I have recurrence relation
$$x_{\alpha+1} = 2 (g(x_\alpha))$$

where
$$g(n)=n - \frac{n\cdot q}{4}$$

and

well actually I know for a fact that $g(x_\alpha)$ is less than or equal to $x_\alpha$ always. So when $g(x_\alpha)$ reaches $2^p$, iterating with the factor $2$ for $2(g(x_\alpha))$ will mean that $p$ increases in $2^p$, thus giving a sequence of  $\{2^p, 2^{p+1}, 2^{p+2},...\}$. Sorry for being vague on what $q$ is, I could not write it properly but $q$ perturbates the numerator, but is never larger than $g(n)$.

The problem is the factor $2$, but I hope to get some insight into how it can converge towards $2^p$.
The $g$-function is behaving chaotically, but i know for a fact that $g(x_\alpha)$ is smaller than $x_{\alpha}$. I can proof that.

[**Edit**: and also $n\cdot q$ is always less than $n$.]

I want to proof that the orbit of $x$ reaches a power of two number that doubles on each iteration. How does one do that?

Is it called fixedpoint or periodic if $x_{\alpha+1} \rightarrow$ $2^p$? where $p$ increase?

I wanted to make a simplification because Im not formal maths writer.

If I shall be a bit more precise using my own words:

The factor $2$ is outside the parenthesis is a fixed number. But the expression inside is reducing if the factor is left out. Only reason its jumping up and down is because the $2$ left-shifts the binary expansion. but subtraction is happening and some borrow and carry techniques should make the dynamical system cancel itself out such that pow$2$ remains.

The question is simply how to proof the orbit reaches $2^p$ where $p$ can be any number at some point in time?

Comment: If you want to give the expression of $g$ as $g(n)$, then on the right side there can be no $x_α$, as that is not the variable of the expression. Can you give an alternative description of what $g$ is, like some code, a graph?

Comment: @LutzL Ah, I did a typo. $x_\alpha$ should be $n$.

Comment: I also added a few things that can make it clearer. I am grateful if someone wants to edit the expressions since my math writing is not the best.

Comment: Is there some rounding operation involved? Your last comments almost sound like that. Else you get a simple geometric sequence, $x_α=(2-\frac{q}2)^αx_0$.

Comment: result is also natural numbers, so i guess rounding yes. Could use the floor function for that. or you could say it is done with integer division. I googled for "chaotic geometric sequence" , but $0$ results. hm. dunno if $x_\alpha = 2(x_{\alpha-1})$ where $x_{\alpha-1}$ is chaotic is a geometric sequence?

Comment: If $q$ is indeed a natural integer, then your choices are $q=0$ and $q=1$ to get any kind of growth. // A geometric sequence is not chaotic, you will have to paint a bigger picture to explain where you expect that chaos is generated.

Comment: @LutzL Yes exactly. $q$ is related to $n$ so, the chaos is from the binary expansion of $n$. So chaos is generated from that initial condition of $n$, but $2n-(n\cdot q)/2$ i find difficult to analyse. Thanks for the replies btw